# my vhdl code for implementing some fsm is not working correctly

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity INCUBATOR2 is
    port(temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    CLK,RESET: in std_logic;
    on_cooler,on_heater: out std_logic;
    CRS:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));

end entity INCUBATOR2;

architecture ARCH of INCUBATOR2 is



TYPE STATE_TYPE_left IS (S1, S2, S3);
SIGNAL STATE,NEXT_STATE   : STATE_TYPE_left;

TYPE STATE_TYPE_right IS (S_OUT,S_1, S_2, S_3);
SIGNAL cooler_STATE,cooler_NEXT_STATE   : STATE_TYPE_right;


begin
    --T<= temprature;
    REG: process (clk, reset) begin
        if reset='1' then
            STATE <= S1 ;
            cooler_STATE<=S_OUT;
        elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
            STATE <= NEXT_STATE ;
            cooler_STATE<=cooler_NEXT_STATE;
        end if ;    
    end process REG ;
   
    CMB:process(STATE,temperature   ,cooler_STATE) 
    begin
        case STATE is
            when S1 => 
                if(temperature  > "00100011" ) then
                    NEXT_STATE<=S2;
                    
                elsif(temperature < "00001111") then
                    NEXT_STATE<= S3;
                end if;
                --cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_OUT;
            when S2 =>
                if(temperature < "00011001" ) then
                    NEXT_STATE<=S1;
                end if;
                case cooler_STATE is
                    when S_OUT=>
                        if(temperature>"00100011") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_1;
                        end if;
                    when S_1=>
                        if(temperature>"00101000") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_2;
                        elsif(temperature<"00011001") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_OUT;
                        end if;
                    when S_2=>
                        if(temperature>"00101101") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_3;
                        elsif(temperature<"00100011") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_1;
                        end if;
                    when S_3=>
                        if(temperature<"00101000") then
                            cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_2;
                        end if;
                end case;
                

                
            when S3 => 
                if(temperature>"00011110" ) then
                    NEXT_STATE<=S1;
                end if;
                --cooler_NEXT_STATE<=S_OUT;
        end case;
        
    end process CMB;
  --  with STATE select
--  heater<= '0' when S1|S2,
--      '1' when S3;
--  cooler<= '0' when S1|S3,
--      '1' when S2;
  --  label if( cooler='1') generate
    --  modul: COOLER port  map(temprature=>T,CRS=>CRS,clk=>clk,reset=>reset);
     --end generate;
    
    OUTPUT : process(STATE,cooler_STATE) 
    begin
            
        case STATE is
            when S1 =>
                on_heater<='0';
                on_cooler<='0';
                
            when S2 =>
                on_cooler<='1';
                on_heater<='0';

                
                case cooler_STATE is
                    when S_OUT =>
                        CRS<="0000";
                    when S_1 =>
                        CRS<="0100";
                    when S_2 =>
                        CRS<="0110";
                    when S_3 =>
                        CRS<="1000";
                    when others=>
                        CRS<="0000";
                end case;
                
            when S3 =>
                on_heater<='1';
                on_cooler<='0';

        end case;
        
    end process OUTPUT;

    
end ARCH;
```

and here is the testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

entity incubator_tb is
end entity;

architecture testbench of incubator_tb is

component INCUBATOR2 is
    port(temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    CLK,RESET: in std_logic;
    on_cooler,on_heater: out std_logic;
    CRS:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end component INCUBATOR2;

signal  CLK, reset: std_logic;
signal  on_cooler,on_heater:std_logic;
signal temperature:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal CRS: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin

modul: INCUBATOR2 port map(
temperature => temperature, clk => clk, reset => reset,
on_cooler => on_cooler,on_heater=>on_heater,CRS=>CRS);

stim: process
begin

temperature <= "00100110";
clk <= '0';
reset <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;

temperature <= "00100110";
clk <= '1';
reset <= '0';

wait for 20 ns;

reset <= '0';
clk <= '0';
temperature <= "00001010";
wait for 20 ns;

reset <= '0';
clk <= '1';
temperature <= "00001010";
wait for 20 ns;

reset <= '0';
clk <= '0';
temperature <= "00100110";
wait for 20 ns;
--clk <= '1';

reset <= '0';
clk <= '1';
temperature <= "00100110";
wait for 20 ns;

reset <= '0';
clk <= '1';
temperature <= "00101010";
wait for 20 ns;


wait;

end process;
end architecture testbench;
```

as in the picture below shows that the outputs of some inputs are being calculated wrong and on_heater never activates...(it is supposed to switch to 1 when the temperature is a)

[image]

can anyone tell me that where am i doing wrong?im so confused
any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask specific questions?  (`can anyone tell me that where am i doing wrong?` isn't specific nor is **fsm not working correctly**.) With a little troubleshooting you'd find [there's a missing clock interval to get to state S3 in the testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U2na.jpg). (You should be able to add the incubator signals to your waveform as done here. You'd find your simply not reaching S3 because the temperature changed to a higher value.)

Comment: Relational operators  for std_logic_vector provided by package std_logic_1164 are  not numeric.

Comment: do u mean i was doing wrong setting the signals in the testbench? @user1155120

Comment: about your second comment  , what do you mean does it interfere in the outputs? @user1155120

Comment: Your preceding comments don't convey understandable questions. In the testbench you're missing a clock cycle between dropping the temperature below a threshold and raising it above a threshold that is needed to traverse from S1 to S3 resulting in  no `on_heater` = '1', something detectable through troubleshooting. If ">" isn't a numeric operation it would be based on comparing elements including metavalues, potentially causing simulation and synthesis mismatch (likely not the case here, a caution - use arithmetic relational operators). There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your design.

Comment: i see, thank u so much.sorry i just couldn't install any simulator so I'm coding online so i cant troubleshoot well.. what do u mean .. should i replace ">" with sth else? because ">" itself is an arithmetic relational operator isn't it? and btw do you know an online free synthesizer? @user1155120

Comment: The ordinary ordering operators are predefined for any single dimensional array type (semantically, immediately following the type declaration) and match on element positional value as per IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators. Assigning numeric meaning to enumeration literals otherwise requires function declarations supplying operator overloads, typically in math packages.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only supposed to design the right-hand state machine (the cooler), you should concentrate on that separate to the left-hand state machine (the main controller).

Talk to your colleague who's designing the main controller to add an output called `enable_cooler` to enable the cooler state machine. The `Incubator` entity could include two entities called `MainController` and `Cooler`.

I've extracted the cooler state machine logic into a separate entity called `Cooler`. It's in three processes which keep the outputs synchronised to both the clock and the state:

1. State Register and Outputs Register.
2. Next State Logic.
3. Next Outputs Logic.

I've also added some `else` clauses to prevent inferred latches, and added some constants to make it more readable and maintainable.

## Cooler State Machine

### State Diagram

[image: Cooler state machine]
Figure 1 – Cooler state machine

---

### VHDL

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Cooler is
    port
    (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        enable: in std_logic;  -- ADDED: From cooler enable signal of modified left-hand state machine.
        temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  -- I've assumed this is a signed temperature.
        crs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture V1 of Cooler is

    type TState is (S_OUT, S_1, S_2, S_3);
    signal state, next_state: TState;

    signal next_crs: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- ADDED to ensure the outputs are synchronised to the clock and state.

    constant TEMPERATURE_P25: integer := 25;  -- ADDED for readability and maintainability.
    constant TEMPERATURE_P35: integer := 35;
    constant TEMPERATURE_P40: integer := 40;
    constant TEMPERATURE_P45: integer := 45;

    constant RPS_0: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";  -- ADDED for readability and maintainability.
    constant RPS_4: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0100";
    constant RPS_6: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0110";
    constant RPS_8: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1000";

begin

    --
    -- State Register and Outputs Register
    --
    process(clock, reset)
    begin
        if reset then
            state <= S_OUT;
            crs <= RPS_0;  -- ADDED to specify outputs for reset condition.
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            state <= next_state;  -- State is synchronised to clock.
            crs <= next_crs;      -- Outputs are synchronised to clock and state.
        end if;
    end process;

    --
    -- Next State Logic
    --
    process(enable, state, temperature)
        variable i_temperature: integer;  -- ADDED for numeric comparisons.
    begin
        if enable then
            i_temperature := to_integer(signed(temperature));  -- I've assumed this is a signed temperature.
            case state is
                when S_OUT =>
                    if i_temperature > TEMPERATURE_P35 then
                        next_state <= S_1;
                    else
                        next_state <= S_OUT;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                    end if;
                when S_1 =>
                    if i_temperature > TEMPERATURE_P40 then
                        next_state <= S_2;
                    elsif i_temperature < TEMPERATURE_P25 then
                        next_state <= S_OUT;
                    else
                        next_state <= S_1;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                    end if;
                when S_2 =>
                    if i_temperature > TEMPERATURE_P45 then
                        next_state <= S_3;
                    elsif i_temperature < TEMPERATURE_P35 then
                        next_state <= S_1;
                    else
                        next_state <= S_2;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                    end if;
                when S_3 =>
                    if i_temperature < TEMPERATURE_P40 then
                        next_state <= S_2;
                    else
                        next_state <= S_3;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                    end if;
                when others =>
                    next_state <= S_OUT;
            end case;
        else
            next_state <= S_OUT;  -- Prevent inferred latch.
        end if;
    end process;

    --
    -- Next Outputs Logic
    --
    process(next_state)
    begin
        case next_state is
            when S_OUT =>
                next_crs <= RPS_0;
            when S_1 =>
                next_crs <= RPS_4;
            when S_2 =>
                next_crs <= RPS_6;
            when S_3 =>
                next_crs <= RPS_8;
            when others =>
                next_crs <= RPS_0;
        end case;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

## Main Controller State Machine

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity MainController is
    port
    (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        on_cooler: out std_logic;
        on_heater: out std_logic;
        enable_cooler: out std_logic  -- ADDED to enable cooler when MainController is in state S2.
    );
end entity;

architecture V1 of MainController is

    type TState is (S1, S2, S3);
    signal state, next_state: TState;

    constant TEMPERATURE_P15: integer := 15;  -- ADDED for readability and maintainability.
    constant TEMPERATURE_P25: integer := 25;
    constant TEMPERATURE_P30: integer := 30;
    constant TEMPERATURE_P35: integer := 35;

    signal next_on_cooler: std_logic;  -- ADDED to ensure outputs are synchronised to the clock and state.
    signal next_on_heater: std_logic;

begin

    --
    -- State Register and Outputs Register
    --
    process(clock, reset)
    begin
        if reset then
            state <= S1;
            on_cooler <= '0';  -- ADDED to specify outputs for reset condition.
            on_heater <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            state <= next_state;          -- State is synchronised to the clock.
            on_cooler <= next_on_cooler;  -- Outputs are synchronised to the clock and state.
            on_heater <= next_on_heater;
        end if;
    end process;

    --
    -- Next State Logic
    --
    process(state, temperature)
        variable i_temperature: integer;  -- ADDED for numeric comparisons.
    begin
        i_temperature := to_integer(signed(temperature));  -- I've assumed this is a signed temperature.
        case STATE is
            when S1 =>
                if i_temperature > TEMPERATURE_P35 then
                    next_state <= S2;
                elsif i_temperature < TEMPERATURE_P15 then
                    next_state <= S3;
                else
                    next_state <= S1;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                end if;
            when S2 =>
                if i_temperature < TEMPERATURE_P25 then
                    next_state <= S1;
                else
                    next_state <= S2;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                end if;
            when S3 =>
                if i_temperature > TEMPERATURE_P30 then
                    next_state <= S1;
                else
                    next_state <= S3;  -- ADDED to prevent inferred latch.
                end if;
            when others =>
                next_state <= S1;
        end case;
    end process;

    --
    -- Next Outputs Logic
    --
    process(next_state)
    begin
        case next_state is
            when S1 =>
                next_on_cooler <= '0';
                next_on_heater <= '0';
                enable_cooler <= '0';
            when S2 =>
                next_on_cooler <= '1';
                next_on_heater <= '0';
                enable_cooler <= '1';  -- ADDED to enable cooler when MainController is in state S2.
            when S3 =>
                next_on_cooler <= '0';
                next_on_heater <= '1';
                enable_cooler <= '0';
            when others =>
                next_on_cooler <= '0';
                next_on_heater <= '0';
                enable_cooler <= '0';
        end case;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

## Incubator Top-Level Entity

This connects the two state machines together, i.e. `Cooler` and `MainController`.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Incubator is
    port
    (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        on_cooler: out std_logic;
        on_heater: out std_logic;
        crs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture V1 of Incubator is

    signal enable_cooler: std_logic;  -- ADDED to enable cooler when MainController is in state S2.

    component MainController is
        port
        (
            clock: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            on_cooler: out std_logic;
            on_heater: out std_logic;
            enable_cooler: out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    component Cooler is
        port
        (
            clock: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            enable: in std_logic;  -- ADDED: From cooler enable signal of modified left-hand state machine.
            temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  -- I've assumed this is a signed temperature.
            crs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

begin

    MC: MainController
        port map
        (
            clock => clock,
            reset => reset,
            temperature => temperature,
            on_cooler => on_cooler,
            on_heater => on_heater,
            enable_cooler => enable_cooler
        );

    CLR: Cooler
        port map
        (
            clock => clock,
            reset => reset,
            enable => enable_cooler,
            temperature => temperature,
            crs => crs
        );

end architecture;
```

## Test Bench

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Incubator_TB is
end entity;

architecture V1 of Incubator_TB is

    constant CLOCK_PERIOD: time := 50 ns;

    signal halt_sys_clock: boolean := false;

    signal clock: std_logic := '0';
    signal reset: std_logic := '0';
    signal temperature: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal on_cooler: std_logic;
    signal on_heater: std_logic;
    signal crs: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    component Incubator is
        port
        (
            clock: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            temperature: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            on_cooler: out std_logic;
            on_heater: out std_logic;
            crs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

begin

    ClockGenerator:
    process
    begin
        while not halt_sys_clock loop
            wait for CLOCK_PERIOD / 2.0;
            clock <= not clock;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process ClockGenerator;

    Stimulus:
    process
    begin
        reset <= '0';
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(38, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD / 4.0;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(12, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(38, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(43, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(48, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        temperature <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(10, temperature'length));
        wait for CLOCK_PERIOD * 4;
        halt_sys_clock <= true;
        wait;
    end process;
    
    INC: Incubator
        port map
        (
            clock => clock,
            reset => reset,
            temperature => temperature,
            on_cooler => on_cooler,
            on_heater => on_heater,
            crs => crs
        );

end architecture;
```

## Simulation

[image: Simulation of incubator]
Figure 2 – Simulation of incubator

---

## Quartus RTL Schematics

[image: Incubator RTL]
Figure 3 – Incubator RTL

---

[image: Main Controller RTL]
Figure 4 – Main Controller RTL

---

[image: Cooler RTL]
Figure 5 – Cooler RTL

---

Comment: thanks so much i really appreciate it!! btw when temperature is 38 for the second time isn't crs supposed to be 4 right away? or there's some logic behind it? becouse it got to be 4 at about 576000 ps.. @tim

Comment: @fatecsa, it's to do with how I interpreted your statement, "the right fsm activates only when the left fsm is in state s2". I added an enable signal to achieve this. If you completely leave out the enable logic, I think you will get what you describe, but the two state machines will be running simultaneously and independently, which will affect how the `Cooler` transitions from `S_3` to `S_OUT` when the temperature changes from 48 to 10.

Comment: @fatecsa, I've changed the enable logic. Previously is was a synchronous output of `MainController`, so it added an extra clock cycle. Now it's an asynchronous signal which will be synchronised within `Cooler`.

Comment: literally thank you much , so you mean the previous code was the answer to the question itself? when the question is saying "the right fsm activates only when the left fsm is in state 2" ,does it mean there has to be a delay in which was in the previous code's simulation?  and btw do you know if this code is synthesizable because i just don't have any synthesizer , i mean i just could not install one.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that I mis-interpreted your original question. I think that the second version without the delay is correct. And it is synthesizable, at least in Quartus. I'll update my post with the Quartus schematics.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help i really appreciate it !! @tim